# VLOOKUP, If exists use other value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

Sorry, not too good with Excel, but what I am trying to achieve is this vlookup located in sheet1 cell R7:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,config!F2:H20,3,FALSE)
```

Which displays a room number, e.g. `1`

However, if the room already exists in the column, I want it to find another value in the VLOOKUP that doesn't already exist in the column.

I check if it exists in the column by using (located in sheet1 cell R8):

```
=COUNTIF(E2:E20,R7)>0
```

So if this query is FALSE, then it's ok to use the VLOOKUP above, but if it returns TRUE it should keep searching until it finds one that is FALSE.

Sheet1:

[image]

config sheet:

[image]

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Can you post some example data and/or screenshots? It's hard to work out a solution without being able to look at the setup. Also, what column are those two formulas in?

Comment: added pictures, sorry

Comment: Where is this formula `=VLOOKUP(F2,config!F2:H20,3,FALSE)` located? Please edit your question to include all information necessary to reproduce a mockup of what you're doing and what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I've wrote where they are located

Comment: Hm. OK. Now I think you have an XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem because I'm not at all clear on what you're trying to *DO*. In `R7` and `R8` for some reason you want to run a procedure one time? Against `F2` specifically? And `F2` is 'Yes' or 'No', and you want to compare it to a Y/N list in `F:F` of config sheet..? This isn't making sense to me, sorry. I think you need to back up a step (or two) and actually describe what your goals are, rather than asking for help with a particular formula that you've tried.

Comment: Cheers, I appreciate the feedback Alex

Answer (score 0):

So the idea seems to be you want a list of rooms that are not yet committed. From that you'll select one by some useful criteria.

I would approach that differently than you are trying. I'd:

1. Create a list somewhere of all the rooms available. Perhaps it is a simple 1-100, perhaps more complicated. Create it in a table off on a helper sheet that you keep hidden or don't. Create it as a Named Range so it is handy but out of sight and easy "mangle-ment" by users.
2. Take it and remove rooms that are in the committed column ("Room" on Sheet1).
3. Choose a method for selecting which of the remaining rooms to commit.

In the following, I create a list of rooms 1-12 in C1:C12. The list of already committed rooms is in A1:A4. You would change those ranges to suit:  use the list of all rooms you created and the Room column on Sheet1. Then I do a comparison of each room on the "exists" list to those in the "committed" list.

At the innermost level of that is an `IF()` making that comparison. It has a `""` result for TRUE (already committed) rooms. I gave it a result for FALSE, but in truth, that doesn't matter and could be left off if the missing argument will not be baffling in a year when you want to update the spreadsheet. Many would find it baffling, so I put it in. But some would find THAT confusing, so "season to taste."

The reason it doesn't matter is that the test will produce an error for rooms not already committed and stop, never getting to the FALSE result. You actually want all those rooms that give errors. So I wrap that with an `IFERROR()` to catch them and give them some useful result:  whatever value that is being tested. So that all gives you a bunch of blanks and a bunch of uncommitted rooms.

I used `UNIQUE()` to reduce the number of blanks to just 1. So now you have a list of uncommitted rooms and a blank. If you do not have `UNIQUE()` (the question is from 2019 and the poster might or might not have it, but anyone with an earlier version would not), you can do the following step, just slightly differently.

Next I `SORT()`-ed the result to get them in order. Not necessary if that doesn't matter, and not necessary if your list of "exists" rooms is in order to start with. But it does put the blank last. If you cannot `SORT()` because you don't have the function, the blank will be first. Having it last lets me select the FIRST "all but one room" using `INDEX()` so the blank is gone. That's easier than selecting the LAST "all but one room" to remove it. Easier to understand. It's not particularly hard to do, but more convoluted so harder to follow a year from now.

If you could not reduce the blanks to just 1, then instead of doing the `COUNTA()` on the results which I do and subtracting 1 from it, do the `COUNTA()` of the results and subtract from it a `COUNTA()` of the "committed" rooms.

Since I only want the single column input as a single column result, using "1" for the column argument in `INDEX()` is not strictly necessary... sometimes. If using a form of `ROW(1:xxx)` as I do here (because... 2019 and so on), it is not needed. But if you do it today and use the nice `SEQUENCE()` function, it will surely be needed. For whatever reason, if using it for a value in `INDEX()`, one usually has to specify the other value, whether that makes much sense or not.

So anyway, you now have an ordered (one way or the other) list of no yet "committed" rooms. You can select it with another `INDEX()` wrapped around it using `,1,1` for row and column, or go wild with `RANDBETWEEN()` using "1" and a formula to count the remaining not "committed" rooms. Perhaps just a `MIN()` to select the lowest numbered not "committed" room. Or... well, you get the idea. Lots of ways. Randomize using `RANDBETWEEN()` some way appropriate if randomizing room use is important, or just take the easy route with `MIN()` if not. Whatever idea seems best to you. You could even do it at the list of "exists" rooms by ordering them in some non-sequential way. Lots of ways to do that.

Answer (score -1):

*You may try this:*

[image]

Formula in cell J2:

=IF(AND(F2="Yes",I2="Yes"),"",IF(F2="Yes",INDEX(H2:H11,MATCH("No",I2:I11,0)),""))

**N.B.**

- For better understanding I've added value in Column I, you may modify them as your need.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.